# How to run application that installed using Snapcraft

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, ngrok, snapcraft

I just installed Snapcraft and then using it to install Ngrok, but unfortunately I still unable to run Ngrox from my terminal.

**My Ngrok Installation**

```
╭─yoesoff@yoesoff-ThinkPad-X220 ~/Documents/labs/hello-world  ‹master› 
╰─➤  sudo snap install ngrok                                                                                                                                         1 ↵
ngrok 2.3.27 from Khiem Doan (khiemdoan) installed
```

**Ngrk Is Listed Now**

```
╭─yoesoff@yoesoff-ThinkPad-X220 ~/Documents/labs/hello-world  ‹master› 
╰─➤  snap list                                                                                                                                                     127 ↵
Name   Version  Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core   16-2.39  6964  stable    canonical✓  core
ngrok  2.3.27   13    stable    khiemdoan   -
```

**But It Does not Work**

```
╭─yoesoff@yoesoff-ThinkPad-X220 ~  
╰─➤  ngrok
zsh: command not found: ngrok
```

My question is how to run an application that installed using snapcraft ?

Thanks you

Comment: I have tried to install another application using Snap but with the same result, I unable to execute the installed application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by Snapcraft poor documentation I think. the only way to run the installed application by Snap should be run by Snap either. Here is how to run an application that installed using Snap:

```
snap run ngrok --version                                                                                                                                        
ngrok version 2.3.27
```

**This way will not work**

```
ngrok
zsh: command not found: ngrok
```

A little bit weird but I think it's better to unzip Ngrok manually instead of using this poor tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the application using `snap run application` (see `snap run --help`).
If you want the application to display in the desktop applications list you should find the `application.desktop` file in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`, then you can symlink it to `.local/share/applications/`.
Or better you can add `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` to `XDG_DATA_DIRS` by putting in `~/.profile` (or `~/.gnomerc` if you want to apply it only to gnome) something like this:

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS="${XDG_DATA_DIRS}:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
```

or if `/etc/profile.d/snapd.sh` exists

```
source /etc/profile.d/snapd.sh
```